# Why MySQL Client 5.7 is not taking complete dump of MySQL Server 8.0?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-error-1064

Backup doesn't completed with full data when taking mysqldump from mysql 5.7 client on Amazon RDS MySQL 8.0

Any issues in this ?

Comment: there was a lot changed, so that it will be impossible that way. try workbench and migrate with that

Comment: ok , upgraded client to 8.0 and restored the data